# Specifying id in mysql replace into

Tags: mysql, replace

I am using mysql REPLACE INTO syntax for my website. below is my test table structure,

```
id  name  address
1   Tom   US
2   Dick  UK
3   Harry US
4   Jony  Spain
```

Query:

```
REPLACE INTO table_name VALUES (3, 'Roni', 'India')
```

now executing this query mysql saying,

**2 row(s) affected.
Inserted row id: 4 ( Query took 0.0003 sec )**

Can anybody explain me what does the above mentioned text means?  Whay **2 Rows affected** ?

Regards

Comment: can you rewrite your query using below syntax
REPLACE INTO <table> (<column1>, <column2>...) VALUES (<value1>, <value2>...)

Comment: Also what output you get when you use your Replace query?

Comment: The REPLACE statement first deletes the record with the same primary key and then inserts the new record. This function returns the number of deleted records plus the number of inserted records.

Comment: Also does your column "id" has any constraint?

Comment: @AshReva yes "id" is the auto increment primary key

Comment: Have updated my answer. Hope it helps you. Other user have also updated answers. If you find it ok then please accept answers and award point to the users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two rows are affected because REPLACE INTO will do a DELETE and then an INSERT on a key collision so you end up with 2 operations, first the DELETE (1 row affected) and then the INSERT (2nd row affected).

You may want to consider other solutions as the DELETE is costly since indexes need to be updated. In many cases an INSERT ... on DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE based query will be faster.

Comment: The "id" field in my table is the auto increment field and when i am running the query the id is remaining same [i.e. 3] ... but according to you it's first delete and then insert a new row. can you please tell me why the auto increment is just stopped working?

You wrote that " DELETE is costly since indexes need to be updated" - does that mean the whole index updated for the table?

Comment: It isn't auto incrementing because you are specifying a value for id explicitly - the value will only auto increment if you don't specify a specific value for it. If you try do a plain old insert while specifying a value for ID (ie: INSERT INTO table_name (600, 'Roni', 'India')) the row will insert and the next auto-increment value will be 601.

Comment: ok .... thanks ... so this is what happens with my table .. after running the query the field with id 3 updated and when i insert a new row the auto increment id becomes 5. So the delete and the re-insert process [i.e. REPLACE] is not effecting the table indexes at all. That's why i was surprised and asked the question. Sorry for my poor English.

Comment: Well they are affecting your indexes, because the DELTE and INSERT both require the indexes to be updated which is a very expensive operation, hence if you use REPLACE INTO a lot you may want to look at other ways to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Ok.... make sense .. thanks a lot .. actually i am not using it a lot ... only one time and i find this things .. anyway thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL REPLACE like UPDATE statement as follows:

```
REPLACE INTO table_name SET column_name1 = value1 AND column2 = value2
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the query like this:

```
EXPLAIN REPLACE INTO table_name VALUES (3, 'Roni', 'India')
```

Notice adding "EXPLAIN" keyword! This way MySQL will explain what's going on.

However note that REPLACE INTO is the same as INSERT INTO, but it will replace the row if exists and insert it if not. So, when exists, it will delete the row then insert the new one and that's why you are having two rows affected.

Comment: Explain is not working with this query ... it's giving sql error

Comment: here it is, **#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REPLACE INTO table_name VALUES (3, 'Roni', 'India')' at line 1**

Comment: Oh I'm Sorry I Don't Know Your MySQL Version, It Has To Be 5.6.3 Or Above To Be Able To Explain On REPLACE... Accroding To MySQL: As of MySQL 5.6.3, EXPLAIN provides information about SELECT, DELETE, INSERT, REPLACE, and UPDATE statements. Before MySQL 5.6.3, EXPLAIN provides information only about SELECT statements.

Comment: ok ... got it ... i will update my mysql version .. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

In your case it look likes id no 3 was delete and then again inserted. That is why it says 2 records affected. Your table might have row 3, Roni and India inserted and deleted row 3,Harry,US